# WPF databinding to a list of datetime objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a combo box that I want to bind to a list of datetime objects, but I want to show the datetime objects in short time format. I'm pretty sure I need to use some form of data template for this, but I can't figure out how to bind to the datetime object's ToShortTime method within the data template.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.0 or 3.5 with SP1, you can simply use the StringFormat to specify the format, for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{}{0:t}'}" />
```

Will show the current date time with short time format ('t' standard date time format modifier, exactly the same as calling DateTime.Now.ToString("t")).

Edit: If you're already in a data template having a DateTime as the DataContext, just use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:t}'}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the Converter property on the binding. Implement IValueConverter to make the change to a string. The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for IValueConverter actually use this as an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named:

```
Combobox.ItemStringFormat
```

here you can provide the Stringformat as usual. No need to Datatemplate the items for this purpose.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDates}"
          ItemStringFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```